# Facebook Unity SDK, broken post processor for iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

Recently updated a unity project from using the Prime31 social plugin, to the official facebook plugin on a Unity 4.3 project.

Noticed a couple of issues with it though regarding the post processor. Firstly It seems that the first time we build a project everything is fine, but successive building then causes the info.plist file to corrupt, an issue we currently deal with by deleting the plist before rebuilding as fortunately facebook sdk is the only thing that then makes changes to it outside of unity itself.

Another issue is that every now and then I'll build and I'll get an error message about a file not found (the main project file which is most definitely where it says it can't find it). Prior to that facebook scripts spit out a log message about "Wrong file format"

Here's where the confusion comes in. That message is logged if the pbx file starts with a specific header and returns null (I imagine this null return is what causes the error). but then in the Encode function for that class, it uses that header value to write the new file. I'm confused as to why its writing a value that it will then in the future consider an invalid file.

any ideas?

Comment: THere is a bug in the postprocessing step we use to add our id to the plist file.  We should have a bug fix out in the near future.  I'd recommend using the "replace" option when you build from unity for now.

Comment: Thanks for the update regarding it being a known issue, for now we've been making do just by having a backup plist file that we use to replace the generated one after builds, as for us this is far less painful than replace builds.

Comment: I'm running into these exact issues the OP talked about. I know this post is a few months old, and supposedly the plist issue is fixed in 5.0.3. I have not verified plist corruption, but the other errors (wrong file format) I get all the time. I've rebuilt the project 3 times now, and as the OP says, it errors on the 2nd time you build an xcode project. Replacing the project does not remedy the issue at that point either.

Answer (score 1):

When building for iOS, the Info.plist may also be corrupted whenever Default Orientation is set to Auto Rotation.  The Info.plist file is created properly on the first build, but subsequent builds results in...

```
<key>UIInterfaceOrientation</key>
<string></string>
</string>
```

... at this point Xcode fails to build the project.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information, knowing this I may just write a small post script of my own to fix the broken file for the time being. Although it does look like the current beta version 5.0.3 fixes the plist appending issue.